# use javax.faces.view.ViewScoped with CDI Spring bean and JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, cdi, jsf-2.2

I'm using Spring 3.1 JSF 2.2.

Annoting Bean with ViewScoped introduced by JSF 2.2 not work.

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class TestBean {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){sysout("Why spring invoke this when initializing context :-( ");}
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml there is an annotation component-scan tag

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
```

Spring 3.1 detect and deal with CDI annotation but @javax.faces.view.ViewScoped not work. I know there is [another solution](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) by creating my own ViewScoped implementation but i want to know why @javax.faces.view.ViewScoped not work

Comment: why do you think spring invoke `@PostConstruct` ? You are not using Spring in this code. Please explain some detail about your problem. A [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is needded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution was removing spring and using a Java EE implementation of CDI

Answer (score -1):

You should notice that JSF annotations will nor work for Spring beans, because JSF beans located in different context.

But view scope implementation is pretty simple. I've created an artifact to solve this problem.

See my github [javaplugs/spring-jsf](https://github.com/javaplugs/spring-jsf) repository.

Answer (score -2):

javax.faces.view.ViewScoped will only work for JSF Managed Bean and not for CDI.

Use javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean annotation if you want to have a correct behavior with View scope instead of javax.inject.Named.

Regards

Comment: You're confusing `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` with `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`. Perhaps you need to catch up the new JSF 2.2 features yet? http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/